# Different apps under same domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, server

I'm exploring the possibilities to have different web apps/environments under the same domain (no subdomains).

Example:

- [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) -> a marketing landing page with Nextjs
- [www.mydomain.com/blog](http://www.mydomain.com/blog) -> a wordpress blog
- [www.mydomain.com/app](http://www.mydomain.com/app) -> a vite+react app login protected

How would I achieve this?
I'm thinking about having a custom nginx server in front of the apps, but how the configuration and the infrastructure would look like on Aws for example?

Answer (score 1):

On AWS you could do this with a [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) distribution, configured with multiple origins at different paths.

Or you could do this with an AWS [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html), configured with path rules to forward traffic from specific paths to specific servers.

Or you could do like you said in your question and setup an Nginx server on an EC2 instance, configured to proxy traffic at different paths to other EC2 instances. This option would require the most manual configuration, and would be the least fault-tolerant option.

Comment: Thanks.Using the cloudfront or alb solutions would be feasible even if the target apps are outside of Aws (eg. the wordpress blog)?

Comment: Only the CloudFront solution would work if some of the targets were outside of AWS.